# How to handle null exception for values mapping through dxa?

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, sdl-tridion, dxa2.2

I have a dxa field which comes from customMetadataPageModelbuilder code but to get this value i have to publish all the pages i want to handle this error for the pages which aren't republished so if value comes null also from dxa end to my webapp client it doesn't breaks the code so i want to know how i can handle null exceptions at semantic mappings from DXA code.
I tried using @Nullable annotation but it didn't work

**The code at which error is coming is:**

@SemanticProperty("localeFrmPublication")
private String localeFrmPublication;

**ERROR iS below**

```
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.buildEntityModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:115)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.createEntityModel(ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.java:88)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.converter.EntityModelDataConverter.convert(EntityModelDataConverter.java:42)
... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.sdl.webapp.common.exceptions.DxaException: Cannot determine view model type for semantic schema names: '[http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core:productSpecificationsEos]'. Please make sure that an entry is registered for this view name in the ViewModelRegistry. Collected exceptions: [com.sdl.webapp.common.exceptions.DxaException: Cannot detect ViewModel for ViewData MvcDataImpl(controllerAreaName=null, controllerName=//www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core, actionName=null, areaName=http, viewName=productSpecificationsEos, regionAreaName=null, regionName=null, routeValues={}, metadata={})]
at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.model.ViewModelRegistryImpl.getMappedModelTypes(ViewModelRegistryImpl.java:82)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.buildEntityModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:95)
... 46 common frames omitted
21:09:52.287 [pool-5-thread-3] ERROR c.s.w.c.i.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl - Exception while getting field data for: private com.canon.webapp.cms.dxa.modules.model.OpenTextMediaManagerItem com.canon.webapp.cms.dxa.modules.model.ProductCoreAttributes.productMainImage
com.sdl.webapp.tridion.fields.exceptions.FieldConverterException: Cannot convert a entity model 2029038 to class com.canon.webapp.cms.dxa.modules.model.OpenTextMediaManagerItem for semantic field productMainImage
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.converter.EntityModelDataConverter.convert(EntityModelDataConverter.java:48)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.converter.EntityModelDataConverter.convert(EntityModelDataConverter.java:17)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.converter.GenericSemanticModelDataConverter.convert(GenericSemanticModelDataConverter.java:72)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultSemanticFieldDataProvider.getFieldData(DefaultSemanticFieldDataProvider.java:138)
at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl.lambda$mapSemanticFields$0(SemanticMapperImpl.java:140)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:692)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:672)
at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl.mapSemanticFields(SemanticMapperImpl.java:119)
at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl.createEntity(SemanticMapperImpl.java:105)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.converter.ContentModelDataConverter.convert(ContentModelDataConverter.java:36)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.converter.ContentModelDataConverter.convert(ContentModelDataConverter.java:19)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.converter.GenericSemanticModelDataConverter.convert(GenericSemanticModelDataConverter.java:72)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultSemanticFieldDataProvider.getFieldData(DefaultSemanticFieldDataProvider.java:138)
at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl.lambda$mapSemanticFields$0(SemanticMapperImpl.java:140)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:692)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:672)
at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl.mapSemanticFields(SemanticMapperImpl.java:119)
at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl.createEntity(SemanticMapperImpl.java:105)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.createViewModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:151)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.buildEntityModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:106)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.createEntityModel(ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.java:88)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.converter.EntityModelDataConverter.convert(EntityModelDataConverter.java:42)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.converter.EntityModelDataConverter.convert(EntityModelDataConverter.java:17)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.converter.GenericSemanticModelDataConverter.convert(GenericSemanticModelDataConverter.java:72)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.converter.ListWrapperConverter.convertValue(ListWrapperConverter.java:59)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.converter.ListWrapperConverter.convert(ListWrapperConverter.java:38)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.converter.ListWrapperConverter.convert(ListWrapperConverter.java:19)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.converter.GenericSemanticModelDataConverter.convert(GenericSemanticModelDataConverter.java:72)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultSemanticFieldDataProvider.getFieldData(DefaultSemanticFieldDataProvider.java:138)
at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl.lambda$mapSemanticFields$0(SemanticMapperImpl.java:140)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:692)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:672)
at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl.mapSemanticFields(SemanticMapperImpl.java:119)
at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl.createEntity(SemanticMapperImpl.java:105)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.converter.ContentModelDataConverter.convert(ContentModelDataConverter.java:36)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.converter.ContentModelDataConverter.convert(ContentModelDataConverter.java:19)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.converter.GenericSemanticModelDataConverter.convert(GenericSemanticModelDataConverter.java:72)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultSemanticFieldDataProvider.getFieldData(DefaultSemanticFieldDataProvider.java:138)
at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl.lambda$mapSemanticFields$0(SemanticMapperImpl.java:140)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:692)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:672)
at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl.mapSemanticFields(SemanticMapperImpl.java:119)
at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl.createEntity(SemanticMapperImpl.java:105)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.createViewModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:151)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.buildEntityModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:106)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.createEntityModel(ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.java:88)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.createEntityModel(ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.java:76)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.createEntityModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:394)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.lambda$addEntitiesToRegionModels$3(DefaultModelBuilder.java:355)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.addEntitiesToRegionModels(DefaultModelBuilder.java:359)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.createRegionModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:341)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.processRegions(DefaultModelBuilder.java:274)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.buildPageModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:264)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.createPageModel(ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.java:60)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.GraphQLContentProvider.loadPage(GraphQLContentProvider.java:181)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.AbstractContentProvider.getPageModel(AbstractContentProvider.java:70)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy158.getPageModel(Unknown Source)
at com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.PageController.getPageModel(PageController.java:305)
at com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.PageController.handleGetPage(PageController.java:123)
at com.canon.webapp.core.thymeleaf.controller.BaseThymeleafController.lambda$0(BaseThymeleafController.java:297)
at com.canon.webapp.core.thymeleaf.config.ContextAwareCallable.call(ContextAwareCallable.java:27)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.sdl.webapp.common.exceptions.DxaException: Exception happened while creating a entity model from: EntityModelData(super=ViewModelData(schemaId=1828646, htmlClasses=null, xpmMetadata=null, metadata=null, extensionData=null, mvcData=null), id=2029038, contextId=0, namespace=tcm, componentTemplate=null, linkUrl=, content=null, binaryContent=null, externalContent=null)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.buildEntityModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:115)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.createEntityModel(ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.java:88)
at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.converter.EntityModelDataConverter.convert(EntityModelDataConverter.java:42)
... 78 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you please ensure the entire Stack Trace is formatted as a code block? Currently only the first part is, making the Question extremely long and hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if a View Model property does not have an associated value in the CM data, the Semantic mapping will just leave the property `null` rather than throw an exception.

However, in your case, there is a specific problem which does make the Semantic mapping throw an exception:

```
Cannot determine view model type for semantic schema names: '[http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core:productSpecificationsEos]'. Please make sure that an entry is registered for this view name in the ViewModelRegistry.
```

So, apparently you don't have a View Model type registered at all for Semantic Entity "productSpecificationsEos". If you do register a View Model type, this exception should disappear.